# how to disable future dates based on some datepicker value in jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using jquery datepicker and I have 4 dates:start_date,end_date,publishing_date and departure_date.Here based on start_date I want to disable future dates upto start_date and similarly based on end_date I want to disable past dates from end date. I am not able to do so, tried many option as onSelect but I just can't get the required disabling.Here is my jquery code.

```
var dateToday = new Date();
var dates = $("#start_date, #end_date").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    minDate: dateToday,
    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
        var option = this.id == "start_date" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
        instance = $(this).data("datepicker"),
        date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);
        dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);
    }
});

$('#departure_date').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    minDate: $('#end_date').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    }).val()
});

$('#publishing_date').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    maxDate: $('#start_date').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    }).val()
});
```

Any suggestions/help is welcome.Thanks in advance.

Also tried using as follows but to no avail.

```
$('#publishing_date').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    maxDate : ($.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', $('#start_date').datepicker("getDate")))
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on suggestions by @Mahesh Sapkal I made following changes to my code.

```
var dateToday = new Date();
var dates = $("#start_date, #end_date").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    minDate: dateToday,
    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
          var option = this.id == "start_date" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
          instance = $(this).data("datepicker"),
          date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);
          if(this.id == "start_date"){
                   $("#publishing_date").datepicker({
                         dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                         minDate: dateToday,
                         maxDate: date
                    });
          }
          if(this.id == 'end_date'){
                   $("#departure_date").datepicker({
                         dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                         minDate: date
                   })
          }
          dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);
     }
```

});
Don't know why but his suggestion of 
$( "#departure_date" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate",date );
isn't working for me.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 $("#start_date").datepicker({
dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
minDate: "+0D",
onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
    var d = parseInt(selectedDate.substring(0, 2));
    var m = parseInt(selectedDate.substring(3, 5));
    var y = parseInt(selectedDate.substring(6, 10));
    var newDate = new Date(y, m - 1, d + 1);
    $("#departure_date").datepicker("option", "minDate", newDate);
}
});

$("#departure_date").datepicker({
dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
minDate: "+0D",
onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
    var d = parseInt(selectedDate.substring(0, 2));
    var m = parseInt(selectedDate.substring(3, 5));
    var y = parseInt(selectedDate.substring(6, 10));
    var newDate = new Date(y, m - 1, d + 1);
    $("#publishing_date").datepicker("option", "minDate", newDate);
   }
 });
```

Comment: what about end_date.It should be dependent on start_date.How do I do this.

Comment: In start date  on select write      $("#end_date").datepicker("option", "minDate", newDate);

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the departure_date & publishing_date after initialization.

Try this.

```
 onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
        var option = this.id == "start_date" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
        instance = $(this).data("datepicker"),
        date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);

        if(this.id === "end_date") {
            $( "#departure_date" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate",date );
        } else {
            $( "#publishing_date" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate",date );
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use [beforeShowDay](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) option to do this.